# angular route component with condition

Tags: angular, routes

I have a routing in application for 'feed' module. In a feed i have two types of posts, and i need to open this post and show full information with direct link, how can i open right component depends on condition, or how i can solve this problem?

```
const feed_routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: ':slug', component: FirstComponent },
            { path: ':slug', component: SecondComponent },
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **common component** to render all the posts. And in it's template render the two types of posts separately like this.

In component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-container',
  styleUrls: ['./app-post-container.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app-posts-container.component.html'
})
export class PostsContainerComponent {
  @input()
  public type;
}
```

In component.html

```
<div>
  <first-component *ngIf="type === 'conditionOne'"></first-component>
  <second-component *ngIf="type === 'conditionTwo'"></second-component>
</div>
```